# rospy.ServiceProxy( ) is not working

Tags: rospy, turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, I am incredibly new to ROS, and I am trying to learn by creating a program with turtlesim.  I am currently writing a node that will call turtlesim's Spawn service, and I am getting an AttributeError: 'module' has not attribute 'ServiceProxy'.

Here is the code I have written:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from turtlesim.srv import Spawn
import rospy

def spawn():
    spawn_turtle = rospy.SerivceProxy('spawn_turtle', Spawn)
    spawn_turtle(50,50,10,"turt")
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spawn()
```

Thank you so much for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223440/rospy.serviceproxy(--)-is-not-working/) by [alambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/25471/alambert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you're misspelled `ServiceProxy`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/25471/alambert/) on 2016-01-04**:
You're right...thank you so much for pointing that out.  I guess that's what happens when I am programming late at night.